# selecting rows from one table that aren't in another table with linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table with userids of people who should be emailed.  When they're emailed a record is added to another table that they were notified.  I need to write a linq query that returns any records in the first table that aren't in notifed table.  Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer here - http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code, this is what you should do(left join) :

```
        List<int?> listA = new List<int?>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        List<int?> listB = new List<int?>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        var result = (from a in listA
                      join b in listB on a equals b into subset
                      from c in subset.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where !c.HasValue
                      select a).ToList();
```

this will render a resulting list of values, which are 6 and 7.

You should look at the values here as if they were PK and FK in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

How about an outer join where the results from the second table are null?

This is from http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx with a minor change to only include those records without matching records:

```
string[] words = {"walking","walked","bouncing","bounced","bounce","talked","running"};
string[] suffixes = {"ing","ed","er","iest"};

var pairs = from word in words 
            from suffix in (from suffix in suffixes where word.EndsWith(suffix) select suffix).DefaultIfEmpty() 
            where String.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix)
            select new {word, suffix};

Console.WriteLine(pairs);
```